# Xcode - How can you determine if a file exists within the app bundle?

Tags: xcode, file, directory

It's ridiculous how many similar questions have been asked yet none are of help to me.

Here is my code:

```
        BOOL exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Flags/%@.jpg", countr.Name]];
        if (exists) {
            NSLog(@"exist");
        }
```

I have a Group named `Flags` with the files inside it. I tried putting this group in the root, code didn't work. then I tried putting it in Resources and both 'Resources/' in the file path and without it did not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the below code:

```
NSString *exists = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"%@", countr.Name ofType:@"jpg"];

//This line checks if anything was stored in the string exists. Nothing would be stored in it if there was no file that existed.
if(exists == nil){ 
    NSLog(@"Doesn't exist");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Exists!");
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it did, but you have a syntax error. Here is the code I used, thanks!

Comment: `      NSString *fullPathToFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                        pathForResource: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@.jpg", countr.Name] ofType: nil];

//            BOOL exists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Flags/%@.jpg", countr.Name] isDirectory:&isDir];
            BOOL exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPathToFile];`

Comment: @user1235155 Nice. Remember to mark as answer and up vote if it helped!